# VB.NET file has become an unreadable format

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, corrupt

So the images below were originally a vb files. I have just opened it and it looks like this and the compiler won't run it. I am unsure whether this is a compiler error or whether it may have become corrupt because the project is stored on an external drive. It is just these two forms that have broken like this; I have one other form and a module in the same project that are okay but the project can't run because of the two that are broke.

[Broken Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltPW4.png)

[Broken Diary Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuRIS.png)

If it changes anything, the designer files for the forms are intact it is just the scripting for the forms elements that is broken.

Also, if I can't identify the cause, is there a way to revert it back to the last working version in visual studio to get my code back? Just because I put a lot of time into it.

Comment: This seems like a question for Super User more than Stack Overflow. One wonders if the files are just zeros (you don't show us), and if so, what other files on your system have been damaged thusly. In particular this answer might be what you need: https://superuser.com/questions/806984/recover-a-file-filled-with-zeroes-nuls-after-power-loss

Comment: This is why you should always keep a backup of your work. Not keeping an up-to-date backup of your work is the "developer equivalent" of playing Russian Roulette.

Comment: This usually happens when Visual Studio crashes (or is in other ways interrupted) during the saving process of those files. If you don't have a backup of them then you most likely won't be able to get them back.

Comment: If you previously compiled the code, you should have executable files in the "obj" and "bin" folders that can be decompiled to recover most of your work.

Comment: @TnTinMn Would it be OK for me to add your comment to my answer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, go ahead and add it if you want.  I figured that this question would have disapeared by now as it really is not a programming question per se.   You may want to caution the OP that the decompiled code may substantially differ from that originally written, especially if Option Strict was Off.

Answer (score 2):

The data in those files is most likely gone.

**IMPORTANT: Do not write *anything* to that disk drive unless you find that you cannot recover those files.**

If you are using a version control system then you can revert to an earlier version.

If you are using Windows 10 and you happen to have stored those files in a location included in what File History saves, you can recover them from that.

If you use some other form of backup, retrieve the files from that.

If you have a separate disk drive with at least as much free space as the one with the corrupted files, you could try running file recovery software as it might be that the zeroed-out file was written to a different place on the HDD.

---

[TinTnMn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592875/tntinmn) pointed out in a comment that if you previously compiled the code, you should have executable files in the "obj" and "bin" folders that can be decompiled to recover most of your work

---

It could be quicker to re-write the code while it is still fresh in your mind.